# Rewriting server variable in IIS 7.5

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule, which changes a server variable with the value of a subdomain.
This works on subdomain.mydomain.nl/somethinghere but not on subdomain.mydomain.nl

```
<rule name="Change code" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="(www\.)?(\w+)\.mydomain\.nl" />
        <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^www.mydomain.nl.*" negate="true" />
        <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^mydomain.nl.*" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="MYVARIABLE" value="{C:2}" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

I have tested 2 urls:
1: subdomain.mydomain.nl/somethinghere
2: subdomain.mydomain.nl

I retrieve the variable in PHP with the following code:

```
echo $_SERVER['MYVARIABLE'];
```

In case of URL 1, the output of this is "subdomain".

In case of URL 2, the output of this is "".

The output of URL 1 is correct, but the output of URL 2 should be "subdomain" too.

I have run a trace of both requests, and they both show that the rule is being matched and executed.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you set a custom server variable, you should start it with `HTTP_`. When you add your own header, it should start with `HTTP_X_` to add a host header starting with an X.

To be honest, I can't really explain why it works without `HTTP_` in some scenarios, but with `HTTP_` it works in all scenarios and that's also how it's documented.

```xml
<rules>
    <rule name="Change code" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="(www\.)?(\w+)\.testsite\.nl" />
            <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^www\.testsite\.nl$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^testsite\.nl$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <serverVariables>
            <set name="HTTP_X_MYVARIABLE" value="{C:2}" />
        </serverVariables>
        <action type="None" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

You can now get the subdomain name with `echo $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MYVARIABLE"];`.

I've also cleaned up your conditional regular expressions to escape the `.`s and also added a `$` to make it truly match the exact domain names.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is the solution. Really strange that i couldnt find this documented anywhre.

Comment: To set request headers, it's necessary to add HTTP_. This is documented [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/665/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference/#Setting_Server_Variables) (see "Note About Request Headers"). What also puzzles me though is why setting a request header always works but setting a server variable doesn't always seem to work.

Comment: @MarcoMiltenburg it seems you have good command over iis rewrite rule. i am new in this area. if possible please have a look at my post and share your valuable answer. my post link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474674/iis-rewrite-rule-change-my-current-aspx-page-hyperlink-href-wrong-way